# Python subprocess Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, snmp, popen

Why its not working? :|

```
import subprocess    
p = subprocess.Popen([r"snmpget","-v","1","-c","public","-Oqv","","-Ln","192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print p
```

Run script:

```
root@OpenWrt:~/python# python w.py

root@OpenWrt:~/python#
```

its printing empty line :|
Bu on the same machine, from shell:

```
root@OpenWrt:~/python# snmpget -v 1 -c public -Oqv -Ln 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7
3623120418
```

I know tere is "-Oqv","", but without it i got error from snmpget...

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that there are SNMP modules for python that let you query directly without executing an external application.  This will mean much faster code with automatic output parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have an empty string in your args:

```
... ,"-Oqv","","-Ln", ...
            ^^
```

Is that possibly causing a problem for snmpget?

You've got two arguments in one, too:

```
"192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7"
```

That should be split in two:

```
"192.168.1.1", "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7"
```

When typing a command on the command line, the shell does this splitting for you. When calling `subprocess.Popen()` in this way, you'll have to do *all* the argument splitting yourself. You'd get the same error if you ran:

```
snmpget -v 1 -c public -Oqv -Ln '192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7'
```

Comment: Without it i got error:
Missing object name
USAGE: snmpget [OPTIONS] AGENT OID [OID]...

Comment: root@OpenWrt:~/python# python w.py
3635981993
Its working now!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the test you're running from the command line to be analogous, you'd need to do the following:

```
snmpget -v 1 -c public -Oqv '' -Ln "192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7"
```

...noting the empty quotes after the `-Oqv`, and that `192.168.1.1` is in the same argument as `1.3.6`..., which is almost certainly not what you want.

As Greg suggests, you should almost certainly split that last argument into two separate array elements, and take out the empty string.

In the mean time, there are simple things you can do to improve error-handling:

- Record exit status.
- Record the contents of stderr, and print them a non-zero exit.

By the way, a bit more whitespace isn't necessarily a bad thing when it comes to readability. Consider the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([
        'snmpget',
        '-v', '1',
        '-c', 'public',
        '-Oqv',
        '-Ln',
        '192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception('snmpget exited with status %r: %r' % (p.returncode. err)
```

Comment: '-Oqv" should be  '-Oqv'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a shell=True parameter to Popen call.

Comment: `shell=True` means your argv gets string-split through a shell; it's really, _really_ the Wrong Answer.

Comment: ...well, it actually does work around the bug in this case (as improper string-splitting is the immediate cause of the bug), but the Right Thing remains actually writing the code such that it doesn't specify a blatantly wrong argv array.

Comment: `shell=True` should not be used. Search on SO for reasons why.